# Labels cut off with `plt.savefig` but not in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a figure with custom-placed axis labels.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(4, 8))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

# hack to set column titles
axes[0, 0].set_title('Observation')
axes[0, 1].set_title('Goal')

for i, env_id in enumerate(["FetchReach-v1", "FetchPush-v1", "FetchPickAndPlace-v1", "SawyerDoor-v1"]):
    axes[i, 0].imshow(np.random.rand(84, 84, 3), aspect='equal')
    axes[i, 0].set_xticks([])
    axes[i, 0].set_yticks([])
    
    # hack to set row labels
    axes[i, 0].set_ylabel(env_id, rotation=0, size='large', horizontalalignment='right')
    
    axes[i, 1].imshow(np.random.rand(84, 84, 3), aspect='equal')
    axes[i, 1].set_xticks([])
    axes[i, 1].set_yticks([])

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

In jupyter, the cell outputs:

[image]

But the saved figure looks like:

[image]

None of `plt.tight_layout`, `subplots_adjust`, etc. seem to prevent the labels from being cut off. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Somehow after struggling with this for about an hour, I used the magic combination of settings to get it to work, which was to call `plt.tight_layout()` right before saving with `bbox_inches='tight'`.